# I want to connect the reception of the email and applications

Tags: postfix-mta

If an email sent on XXXX@YYYY.ZZZ, I want to put the contents of the email in a database, but how may realize it? 
I use postfix to MTA.

Comment: This does NOT belong on serverfault, as the question is about writing a program that will get an input from the mail server and put it into a database. There are no ready tools that do it, You must write one Yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you definitely must, write a program to process the input (say /usr/bin/your_program) and place this in /etc/aliases:

```
intended-local-address: "|/usr/bin/your_program"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used [fetchmail](http://catb.org/esr/fetchmail/fetchmail-man.html). If You configure it right, it can make a **blocking** call to a remote IMAP server (it will hang until a mail is received, how cool is that, no active polling!). It handles many kinds of mail protocols. It puts the email with it's headers into a program of Your choice (I used python and it's builtin mail parsing libary).

I must say I am proud of this solution, as it was relatively easy to setup and very effective on the end.

Few more things worth noting:

1. The connection times out or resets eventually (after several hours, sometimes several weeks). I suspect that the IMAP server was being restarted.
2. Don't try to parse the email by Yourself. I gave up after debugging the 5th way of sending email body and then used the existing lib.
3. After the poll finishes, do a *sleep 5* or something before You poll again. My mail program once felt into an infinite loop with another one and the sleep 5 saved me.